# in_category() self defined $post->ID

Tags: wordpress

I have this code:

```
function add_cert_id_to_notes( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $products = $order->get_items();

    foreach( $products as $product ){

        $product_id = $product['product_id'];

        $order->add_order_note( 'First Test: '.$product_id, 0 );

        if( in_category('188', $product_id)){

            $order->add_order_note( 'Second Test: '.$product_id, 0 );

        }
        else {
            $order->add_order_note( 'Second Test: FAIL', 0 );
        }

    }

}
```

Using WooCommerce, but that's not the problem. The issue is with `in_category()`. I'm not doing this is a standard loop, I've defined my post ID with $product_id.

Problem is, it keeps returning the failure notice I have set up.  I've tried with both the category ID and slug and I still get nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `in_category` is only for post's category.
Document says `The given categories are checked against the post's categories' term_ids, names and slugs.` So it only check for **post** i think.

Try following function:-

```
function add_cert_id_to_notes( $order_id )
{
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $products = $order->get_items();

    foreach( $products as $product )
    {
        $categories = array();
        $product_id = $product['product_id'];

        $order->add_order_note( 'First Test: '.$product_id, 0 );

        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
        foreach ( $terms as $term )
        {
            $categories[] = $term->term_id;
            $categories[] = $term->slug;
        }
        //if you want to check category slug than you also can use `slug` as $your_cat_id.
        //`$term->slug` is also in $categories array..
        $your_cat_id = '188';
        if ( in_array( $your_cat_id, $categories ) )
        {
            $order->add_order_note( 'Second Test: '.$product_id, 0 );
        } else {
            $order->add_order_note( 'Second Test: FAIL', 0 );
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested this function and its working...Hope it will work for you..

Comment: So you're saying it only works for post-type posts and not objects or custom post types?

Comment: yes, but i am not sure about that documents...
Try `Ctrl+Click` on `in_category` if you are using editor...you will find function description...

Comment: Crtl+Click where?  What editor software are you using?

Comment: open `wp-includes/category-template.php` and find `in_category` function...than see description above that function...

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing something similar to your solution with wp_get_post_terms.  Thanks for the info.